# r: How to read the correlation matrix in `lmer`?

Tags: r

I was fitting a linear mixed effect model using `lme4` package in `r`, and the results show as:

```
m4 <- lmer(y ~ 0 + X + (0+ X|subject))
```

[image]

I was wondering how could I read the correlation matrix in the green box and use it for later calculation?

I tried

```
VarCorr(m4)
```

and it gives

[image]

I also tried

[image]

Is there a way to just get the `Corr` part?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `str` of `m4`?

Comment: [This help page](https://rdrr.io/cran/lme4/man/VarCorr.html) seems informative. Wrapping `.as.data.frame(VarCorr(m4))` looks like it should return a data.frame that will be easier to extract items from.

Comment: @Chase Thanks very much, but I actually tried that and did not get what I want. I will edit my post according to this statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. Save the data.frame object and you'll have an easy to manipulate object. 
Do this:

```
m<-lmer(Sepal.Length~0+Species|Sepal.Length,iris)
res<-summary(m)[13][[1]]

res1<-res$Sepal.Length #replace with res$Subject as per OP's question
attr(res1,"correlation")


                      Speciessetosa     Speciesversicolor Speciesvirginica
Speciessetosa                 1                 1                1
Speciesversicolor             1                 1                1
Speciesvirginica              1                 1                1
```

Comment: Thanks, but could I get the `Corr` part just as a matrix in the green box?